# Android UI is responsive, but is not redrawn (elements are not updated)

Tags: android

I'm creating a video-player. Sometimes it seems that the UI is not being redrawn.

Every focused element in my UI has a drawable background. But sometimes when I click on an element, it's background doesn't change.

For instance, I can click on my pause button. The video is paused, but the button is not focused on the screen. I then can click on another button and everything works fine except the UI is not updated. The same with `HorizontalGridView` and `SeekBar`.

At the same time the `VideoView` works fine (it plays/pauses the video). So I know that all the events have been triggered properly (but again, that isn't drawn on the screen).

I want to point out, that it happens occasionally. Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. Moreover, I couldn't reproduce this problem on another device. So it seems the problem is related to hardware. How can I debug this problem?

I can post the code here, but it's 700 lines and it won't give you anything.

Comment: How have you implemented the buttons? Does the coreographer work fine or is it skipping frames like hell?

Comment: I don't see any coreographer  related messages in the logcat. And the video plays smoothly. If I did too much work on the main thread, wouldn't it affect the VideoView?